# Charts graphics software

Tags: software-recommendation

I need to do a presentation of a product with charts (Pie and Bar charts).

I use LibreOffice for documentation, but charts are not very beautiful.

Someone could recommend any software to generate charts ?

It's very important that charts will be beautiful, with 3D effect, gradients, etc.

Thanks

Comment: You know that you can customise the charts, change colours, use 3D, use gradients and redefine nearly everything?

Answer (score 1):

[R](http://www.r-project.org/) has very good charting capabilities ([click here for a gallery of examples with sources](http://addictedtor.free.fr/graphiques/)).

It is free and installable from the repositories. The main package is `r-base`, several additional packages are also available.

Note that R is not a spreadsheet. It is a programming environment -- a bit of work is necessary to obtain what you want. There are, however, several tutorials ([this](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/r/) and [this for pies](http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/pie.html)).

Answer (score 1):

I recently discovered gnuplot is not as difficult as I thought. New version can output in HTML5. As per piecharts try circles.
http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.4/circles.html

Not sure about the 3D effects but you can output it as an SVG and have a play around with an vector graphics editor like inkscape.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you tried mathgl too. It's specifically made for nice 3D charts.